# Can page level locks cause a deadlock between 2 transactions trying to lock 2 different rows on the same page?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

According to [postgres docs section 13.3.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/explicit-locking.html)

> In addition to table and row locks, page-level share/exclusive locks
> are used to control read/write access to table pages in the shared
> buffer pool. These locks are released immediately after a row is
> fetched or updated. Application developers normally need not be
> concerned with page-level locks, but they are mentioned here for
> completeness.

My understanding is I need not to be concerned whether my transactions are large enough that they may lock enough rows long enough that a situation happens where T1 has a lock on R1 on P1 and wants to lock R2 on P2 but cannot do that because T2 has a lock on R3 on P2 and it is not releasing it until it gets a lock on R4 on P1.

> T -> transaction
> P -> page
> R -> row

Is this assumption correct or should I make my transactions short enough that this kind of lock is less likely to happen?

Comment: My understanding is, that those page locks are held for only very brief moments when the page data is accessed **in memory**. They are not kept for the duration of the transaction and they are not applied to blocks on disk.

Comment: Based on your reply and @Laurenz Albe's I am pretty confident that is the case but now I am interested on finding more about how these page locks work and other than the code itself there seems to be no official source. Do any of you know of any internal design spec that I can check instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page level locks are always held for a short time, no matter how long your transaction takes. Different from other locks, they are *released before commit*, immediately when they are no longer required.

Moreover, page locks are always taken in a way that they cannot participate in deadlocks (unless PostgreSQL has a bug).

### Details:

Page locks are taken using the `LockPage` function in `src/backend/storage/lmgr/lmgr.c`.  Currently, they are only used with GIN indexes during index cleanup, when the pending list is integrated into the main index (function `ginInsertCleanup` in `src/backend/access/gin/ginfast.c`): the metapage is locked to prevent concurrent execution of the function.

Comment: do you know of any claim about that on postgres official documentation/spec? I am looking for it but cannot see any reference and the part I quoted seems rather vague...